# Shopify sort by with multiple filters

Tags: shopify

I am trying to add a sort by functionality in my Shopify theme.
I am already filtering collections using the storefront filtering.

It all works fine, but issue appears when more than one filter has been selected.
The sorting always replaces one of the existing filters with the code I have.

Does someone know how can I add/remove the *&sort_by* without affection the *&filter* values?

For example, once filtering more than once, the url looks like this:
***.../new-arrivals?filter.v.option.size=XS&filter.v.option.size=S&sort_by=price-descending***

Once I sort:
***.../new-arrivals?filter.v.option.size=XS&sort_by=price-descending***

```
Shopify.queryParams = {};
if(location.search.length) {
  for(var aKeyValue, i = 0, aCouples = location.search.substr(1).split('&'); i < aCouples.length; i++) {
    aKeyValue = aCouples[i].split('=');
    if (aKeyValue.length > 1) {
      Shopify.queryParams[decodeURIComponent(aKeyValue[0])] = decodeURIComponent(aKeyValue[1]);
    }
  }
}
document.querySelector('.sort-by').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var value = e.currentTarget.value;
  Shopify.queryParams.sort_by = value;
  location.search = new URLSearchParams(Shopify.queryParams).toString();
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided isn't functional because it employs an object to store all the query parameters. However, multiple keys with the same name can't exist within an object. Therefore, the loop replaced the previous values of a key, and only the last value was retained, which was then added to the final URL parameters.

Instead, try using the following code, which creates an array that includes all current query parameters and their respective values, except for the `sort_by` parameter. The code then adds the `sort_by` parameter with its newly selected value to the array. Finally, the values of the array are joined using the `&` character, and the resulting string is used as the new value of the `window.location.search` property.

```js
// update the sort_by parameter of the current url when the sort-by select is changed
document.querySelector('.sort-by').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    var params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
    var newparams = []
    for (let param of params) {
        var k = param[0]
        var v = param[1]
        if (k !== 'sort_by') {
            newparams.push(encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(v))
        }
    }

    newparams.unshift('sort_by=' + e.currentTarget.value)
    window.location.search = newparams.join('&')
})
```